# Filtering orders by date bring wrong results

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-craftcommerce

I'm having a problem with wrong results when filtering order by date.

I use this code:

```
{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered(' >= 2016-07-01 00:00:00').dateOrdered(' <= 2016-07-01 23:59:59').find() %}
```

The last order has been placed on 2016-06-29, and there has been no orders placed on 2016-07-01, so I would expect order to have no results. However it just lists all orders in the system.

If I change the date to 2016-06-10, the result is empty - as expected.

Is this bug in Craft / Craft Commerce, or do I miss something?

How do I make sure I get no results, if there have been no orders on this date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
{% set firstDayOfMonth = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-01" %}
{% set daysInThisMonth = firstDayOfMonth|date('t') %}
{% set lastDayOfMonth  = year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ daysInThisMonth %}

{% set thisMonthsOrders = craft.commerce.orders.dateOrdered('and', '>= ' ~ firstDayOfMonth, '<= ' ~ lastDayOfMonth) %}
```

Comment: @YuriSalimovskiy this won't return elements for the last day of the month. You need to add 23:59 as a time to `lastDayOfMonth` or use `date_modify('first day next month')` instead.

Comment: My dates are provided with GET variable, so that's not a problem. My problem was solved with 'and' keyword